# Generating phonetically similar phrases

Tags: libraries

## The Question

I'm writing some song parodies (*not* passwords) and I thought it would be cool if there was some library/module/package or tool that I could use to generate phonetically similar phrases (without spending hours trying to get the darn thing to even work properly). **Ideally, whatever this is would take a word (a single word) or phrase (a set of words) and return a list of phonetically (not semantically) similar phrases (not rhymes). Does anyone know of anything like this?**

For the songs, I'd probably just use this to get some ideas, and not actually use them in the parody, but I think that this could be fairly useful for other purposes, such as writing chatterbots that make up puns and such, and also the obvious speech-recognition stuff.

---

### But wait!

#### Why you shouldn't vote to close this

I understand that there are many similar questions on SO right now, but while I know about how the Soundex system can be used to calculate phonetic similarity, I am a little reluctant to undergo a full-blown "Hey, let's use a Soundex lib and a wrapper for WordNet and write my own library for this!" project... (There's a cool module in swipl that uses this, but it doesn't generate anything.)

#### Before you say anything about that PHP library thing.....

I understand that there is a library for PHP that does something like what I'm looking for, but I don't know any PHP (C#, Prolog [preferably SWI, but I can always port things], Java, Python, Javascript [though that would not be the most convenient], R, Visual Basic for Applications [why am I even mentioning that?], and Emacs Lisp are fine, and I might even be willing to pick up Haskell, Ruby, Octave, Scala, or Perl if there's something that fits my purposes perfectly). No Fortran or BASIC please. :)